# Get data from JSON request

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to access certain data from a JSON request, but I can't get far enough in the data to get what I need.

Site that I use: https://tibiadata.com/doc-api-v2/guilds/

The good example is the 1 under "One specific guild of Tibia"

The information I'm trying to get is the name/status under guild -­> members -> characters.

This is what I do so far:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); //Get the info into root
JSONObject guildArray = root.getJSONObject("guild"); //Get the info under "guild"
JSONArray members = guildArray.getJSONArray("members"); //Get the info unders members
```

at this point

```
System.out.println(members.get(0));
```

would give

```
{"characters":[{"nick":"Coffee time","vocation":"Elite Knight","level":336,"joined":"2017-12-27","name":"Pelli Moulante","status":"online"}],"rank_title":"Leader"}
```

So the only part I miss, is getting into "characters" to get the name/status information.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `JsonObject charac = members.getJsonObject(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`members.get(0)` will return the first `JsonObject` in members `JSONArray`

```
{
    "rank_title": "Ivory Guardian",
    "characters": [
      {
        "name": "Tanthalas the Fourth",
        "nick": "Legendary naab",
        "level": 138,
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "joined": "2008-06-17",
        "status": "offline"
      }, {
        "name": "Bubbax",
        "nick": "Deco man",
        "level": 230,
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "joined": "2014-08-29",
        "status": "offline"
      },
    ]
  }
```

From this get the `characters`, `JSONArray` which consists of `JsonObject`, then iterate `JSONArray` using for loop

```
for(Object obj : members.getJsonObject(0).getJSONArray("characters")) {

           JSONObject p = (JSONObject) obj;
           System.out.println(p.get("name");
           System.out.println(p.get("status");
           }
```

Comment: Got a error of incompatible types on "JSONObject obj". Required:Object

Comment: "foreach not applicable to type 'org.json.JSONObject'" if I force the type, its give that